# Set conditions while using uib-popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a registration form by using AngularJS. The form must prompt user for incorrect input while attempting submission.

I used `uib-popover` provided by UI Bootstrap to implement the popover function while clicking "save" button. Here is what I've done so far for the click button on the web page:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" uib-popover = 
"Wrong email format: {{formDetail.email_test}}" popover-title=
"{{errorMsgPopover.title}}" style="height:30px; padding:4px 12px;"
ng-click="beforeAndAfterDemo()">Save</button>
```

Now I can successully retrieve the data I want from the controller. It looks like the following:

[image]

However, what I wish to do is to implement *form validation*, and the popover should only be shown when given input is not correct.

Could you show me how to implement **conditional** `uib-popover`? Assume I already have some logic implement by JavaScript and I have put them all inside the controller.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either use the `popover-enable` property (which accepts `true` or `false`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3kpm2e0n/

Or you could have 2 buttons. One with the popover and the other without. Either one would be displayed with an `ng-if`